# INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with Condition

Tags: mysql

My table have Cas field, I want implement CompareAndSet in save operation

here is my sql code

```
INSERT INTO `test_cas_table`(id,name,cas) VALUES(3, "test data", 2) 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    id = VALUES(id),
    name = VALUES(name),
    cas = IF(cas = VALUES(cas) - 1, VALUES(cas) , "update failure")
```

because cas field is BIGINT, when `cas != VALUES(cas) - 1` will set it with "update failure" cause this execution to fail

but this way is so ugly, Is there a pretty implementation?

and I want know did postgresql have pretty implementation?

I want implement it in once execution

Comment: Why to keep condition in database instead of application?

Comment: @RedBoy what mean's application?

Comment: You should not handle duplicated information this way. What you need to do is check for possible data duplication inside your application (your website, mobile app, desktop app, etc) before persisting new info.

Comment: As exactly mentioned by @DiegoVictordeJesus, you should be handling it in App.

Comment: @DiegoVictordeJesus check it in application ? and how to maintain consistency?

Comment: What do you mean by consistency?

Comment: @DiegoVictordeJesus A single question, now have (uuid,name,cas) fields table, I want to Insert/Update one data, I don't know this primary key exist or not, How to save it and maintain consistency

Answer (score 0):

Is your identity column auto generated? If so, there's no need to check for duplicates. Just insert your new information and your database will handle it.

However, if you have an identity column which isn't auto generated (like an email or official document instead of an auto increment integer primary Key), you need to first query your database looking for the value You're about to persist. That way, instead of receiving a SQLException (Java), you check your query result and tell the user to change its email or official document if it was already taken by another user.